# Looking to optimize multiple JOINs into one dynamic JOIN - Possible?

Tags: sql, t-sql

So I currently have a query that pulls in buyer and seller names into a single column value. I am utilizing a `CASE` statement for if one of the buyer or seller values is `NULL`, and also since the user can delete the buyer or seller and it retains its original `Sequence` value (1, 2, 3, etc..) So for instance, say I have the following entries in the BuyerSeller table:

```
OrdersID | Sequence | BuyerSellerType | FormalName
------------------------------------------------------
1        | 1        | 0               | Billy Bob
1        | 2        | 0               | Sally Sue
1        | 1        | 1               | Joe Dirt
1        | 3        | 1               | Dwayne Johnson
```

My `SELECT` statement below will return the following:

```
BuyerFormalName      | SellerFormalName
-----------------------------------------------
Billy Bob, Sally Sue | Joe Dirt, Dwayne Johnson
```

Here's the statement. Now, I am just trying to see if there is any way to dynamically or more easily produce the same results without the need for so many `JOINs`? I am getting the results I want, but I am looking to fine tune my skills and knowledge, especially since I might have to potentially add >3 more `JOINs`. Any insight would be very much appreciated!

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN ISNULL(B.FormalName,'') <> '' AND ISNULL(B2.FormalName,'') <> '' AND ISNULL(B3.FormalName,'') <> ''
            THEN B.FormalName + ', ' + B2.FormalName + ', ' + B3.FormalName
        WHEN ISNULL(B.FormalName,'') <> '' AND ISNULL(B2.FormalName,'') = '' AND ISNULL(B3.FormalName,'') <> ''
            THEN B.FormalName + ', ' + B3.FormalName
        WHEN ISNULL(B.FormalName,'') <> '' AND ISNULL(B2.FormalName,'') <> '' AND ISNULL(B3.FormalName,'') = ''
            THEN B.FormalName + ', ' + B2.FormalName
        WHEN ISNULL(B.FormalName,'') = '' AND ISNULL(B2.FormalName,'') <> '' AND ISNULL(B3.FormalName,'') <> ''
            THEN B2.FormalName + ', ' + B3.FormalName
        WHEN ISNULL(B.FormalName,'') = '' AND ISNULL(B2.FormalName,'') <> '' AND ISNULL(B3.FormalName,'') = ''
            THEN B2.FormalName
        WHEN ISNULL(B.FormalName,'') = '' AND ISNULL(B2.FormalName,'') = '' AND ISNULL(B3.FormalName,'') <> ''
            THEN B3.FormalName
        ELSE B.FormalName
    END AS 'BuyerFormalName'
    ,CASE
        WHEN ISNULL(S.FormalName,'') <> '' AND ISNULL(S2.FormalName,'') <> '' AND ISNULL(S3.FormalName,'') <> ''
            THEN S.FormalName + ', ' + S2.FormalName + ', ' + S3.FormalName
        WHEN ISNULL(S.FormalName,'') <> '' AND ISNULL(S2.FormalName,'') = '' AND ISNULL(S3.FormalName,'') <> ''
            THEN S.FormalName + ', ' + S3.FormalName
        WHEN ISNULL(S.FormalName,'') <> '' AND ISNULL(S2.FormalName,'') <> '' AND ISNULL(S3.FormalName,'') = ''
            THEN S.FormalName + ', ' + S2.FormalName
        WHEN ISNULL(S.FormalName,'') = '' AND ISNULL(S2.FormalName,'') <> '' AND ISNULL(S3.FormalName,'') <> ''
            THEN S2.FormalName + ', ' + S3.FormalName
        WHEN ISNULL(S.FormalName,'') = '' AND ISNULL(S2.FormalName,'') <> '' AND ISNULL(S3.FormalName,'') = ''
            THEN S2.FormalName
        WHEN ISNULL(S.FormalName,'') = '' AND ISNULL(S2.FormalName,'') = '' AND ISNULL(S3.FormalName,'') <> ''
            THEN S3.FormalName
        ELSE S.FormalName
    END AS 'SellerFormalName'
FROM
    Checks C
    LEFT JOIN BuyerSeller B
        ON C.OrdersID = B.OrdersID
        AND B.Sequence = 1
        AND B.BuyerSellerType = 0
    LEFT JOIN BuyerSeller B2
        ON C.OrdersID = B2.OrdersID
        AND B2.Sequence = 2
        AND B2.BuyerSellerType = 0
    LEFT JOIN BuyerSeller B3
        ON C.OrdersID = B3.OrdersID
        AND B3.Sequence = 3
        AND B3.BuyerSellerType = 0
    LEFT JOIN BuyerSeller S
        ON C.OrdersID = S.OrdersID
        AND S.Sequence = 1
        AND S.BuyerSellerType = 1
    LEFT JOIN BuyerSeller S2
        ON C.OrdersID = S2.OrdersID
        AND S2.Sequence = 2
        AND S2.BuyerSellerType = 1
    LEFT JOIN BuyerSeller S3
        ON C.OrdersID = S3.OrdersID
        AND S3.Sequence = 3
        AND S3.BuyerSellerType = 1
```

Comment: First thought: you can do a union on all 'Sx' and have one big 'S' table. That would simplify your 'case'. Same for 'Bx'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
WITH BuyerSeller
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        VALUES  (1,1,0,'Billy Bob'),
                (1,2,0,'Sally Sue'),
                (1,1,1,'Joe Dirt'),
                (1,3,1,'Dwayne Johnson')
    ) A(OrdersID,[Sequence],BuyerSellerType,FormalName)
)

SELECT DISTINCT OrdersID,
                STUFF(Bname,1,2,'') AS BuyerFormalName,             
                STUFF(Sname,1,2,'') AS SellerFormalName
FROM BuyerSeller A
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT ', ' + FormalName
                FROM BuyerSeller B
                WHERE       A.OrdersID = B.OrdersID
                        AND BuyerSellerType = 0
                ORDER BY [Sequence]
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ) CA(Bname)
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT ', ' + FormalName
                FROM BuyerSeller B
                WHERE       A.OrdersID = B.OrdersID
                        AND BuyerSellerType = 1
                ORDER BY [Sequence]
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ) CA2(Sname)
```

Results:

```
OrdersID    BuyerFormalName        SellerFormalName
----------- ---------------------  -----------------------
1           Billy Bob, Sally Sue   Joe Dirt, Dwayne Johnson
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. I was never able to figure out an applicable method for `CROSS APPLY`, but your example has given a lightbulb moment for me. This is going to come in very handy for multiple facets of my scripting, so thank you immensely! So glad to learn something new.

Comment: I could have used a subquery instead of CROSS APPLY since I'm only returning 1 row but personally, I think CROSS APPLY is so much easier to read which means easier editing and debugging

Answer (score 0):

I still prefer old-style MAX/CASE in such a case if the number of rows/values is known (and small):

```
SELECT
   c.OrdersID,
   BuyerFormalName,
   SellerFormalName
FROM Checks C
LEFT JOIN
 (
   SELECT
      OrdersID,
      STUFF(MAX(CASE WHEN Sequence = 1 AND BuyerSellerType = 0 THEN ', ' + FormalName ELSE '' end) +
            MAX(CASE WHEN Sequence = 2 AND BuyerSellerType = 0 THEN ', ' + FormalName ELSE '' end) +
            MAX(CASE WHEN Sequence = 3 AND BuyerSellerType = 0 THEN ', ' + FormalName ELSE '' end), 1,2,'') AS BuyerFormalName,
      STUFF(MAX(CASE WHEN Sequence = 1 AND BuyerSellerType = 1 THEN ', ' + FormalName ELSE '' end) +
            MAX(CASE WHEN Sequence = 2 AND BuyerSellerType = 1 THEN ', ' + FormalName ELSE '' end) +
            MAX(CASE WHEN Sequence = 3 AND BuyerSellerType = 1 THEN ', ' + FormalName ELSE '' end), 1,2,'') AS SellerFormalName
   FROM BuyerSeller
   GROUP BY OrdersID
 ) AS b
ON C.OrdersID = B.OrdersID
;
```